# issue in JOLT transformation

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Please help me with this jolt transformation to split record. There are subarrays which includes Tags information, now I want to split the subarrays and create a new arrays to include all the information in a single place.

**input**:

```json
{
  "Size": 200,
  "SnapshotId": "",
  "State": "in-use",
  "Tags": [
    {
      "Key": "BusinessUnit",
      "Value": "Platform"
    },
    {
      "Key": "DR",
      "Value": "Critical"
    }
  ]
}
```

**expected output**:

```json
[
  {
    "Size": 200,
    "SnapshotId": "",
    "State": "in-use",
    "Tags_Key": "BusinessUnit",
    "Tags_Value": "Platform"
  },
  {
    "Size": 200,
    "SnapshotId": "",
    "State": "in-use",
    "Tags_Key": "DR",
    "Tags_Value": "Critical"
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi @priyanka, I think the expected output is not a valid JSON. Please check once

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following methods

**Method 1** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Tags": {
        "*": { // the level of the indexes of the "Tags" array
          "@2,Size": "[&1].Size", // go 2 levels up the tree to grab therelated value
          "@2,SnapshotId": "[&1].SnapshotId",
          "@2,State": "[&1].State",
          "*": "[&1].&2_&" // generate array-wise results for all attributes with each objects 
                           // of the array while returning the literal "Tags" by using &2
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Demo 1** :

[image]

**or**

**Method 2** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "Others.&", // The elements other than "Tags" array
      "Tags": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Tags": {
        "*": {
          "@2,Others": { "*": "[&2].&" },
          "*": "[&1].&2_&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**Demo 2** :

[image]

The second method is more dynamic. Since, need to write the **other** elements individually within the first method

Comment: Thanks a lot @Barbaros Özhan, it worked like champ!