# Splitting a record into multiple records

Tags: json, jolt

I have a JSON record:

```json
{
  "field1": "Tom"
  "field2": "x::y::z",
  "field3": "a::b::c"
}
```

What I want is to split this record into multiple records where each record represents the pairing of field2 and field 3.

It means first record would have  field2 as x and field3 as a, second record would have field2 as y and field3 as b and so on.

What API of jolt can help here?

Expected output:

```json
{
  "field1": "Tom",
  "field2": "x",
  "field3": "a"
}
{
  "field1": "Tom",
  "field2": "y",
  "field3": "b"
}
{
  "field1": "Tom",
  "field2": "z",
  "field3": "c"
}
```

I think first stage of transformation can be:

```json
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "field2": "=split('::', @(1,field2))",
    "field3": "=split('::', @(1,field3))"
  }
}
```

This would result into field2 and field3 being converted to an array.

Comment: Modified post to add expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the ***split*** the values within **modify**, and then separate key-value pairs into individual objects within **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*2|*3": "=split('::', @(1,&))"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*2|*3": {
        "*": {
          "@3,field1": "[&1].field1",
          "@": "[&1].&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: I think it wont replicate field1 in each record. Let me try though.

Comment: Because there's already no exact "field1" attribute within your case @Mandroid

Comment: I update my question.

Comment: I've just edited the answer @Mandroid

Comment: Thanks. Just a query. If there are multiple field1 like fields(ie having single value), I need to repeat similar for them OR there can be an easier way, like some wildcard based approach?

Comment: You're welcome @Mandroid . You might check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76718374/5841306) , which's one previous answers of mine , as a sample case to show a more dynamic one for your query.